# iOS/Flutter App Crash: io.flutter.1.raster EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios, flutter, crash

Over the past year, I've been using Flutter 2.2.2 without upgrading the Flutter version. However, the latest version of the app is experiencing this crash, with a crash rate of 4%. really strange!

```
Crashed: io.flutter.1.raster EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
0 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
1 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
2 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
3 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
4 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
5 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
6 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
7 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
8 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 940
9 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 288
10 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 1852
11 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
12 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
13 Flutter (Missing UUID 91454c393ae036499eb3dd4198405571)
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start + 148
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Facing the same issue when using the below version for iOS project. 
Flutter 3.4.0-30.0.pre 
Dart 2.19.0